# Incorrect argument label in call (have 'uiImage:', expected 'from:')

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I try to create an image with the content that I get from an API, this error appears.

```
Image(uiImage: (imageLoader.data.count == 0) ? UIImage(named: "apple")! : UIImage(data: imageLoader.data)!)
```

The error that appears is

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'uiImage:', expected 'from:')

Comment: I had a similar error but something other than from.. I found this to just be a compiler error. So the problem was actually elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you hardcode `uiImage` as the argument label while it  should be `from` so replace

```
Image(uiImage: (imageLoader.data.count == 0) ? UIImage(named: "apple")! : UIImage(data: imageLoader.data)!)
```

with

```
Image(from: (imageLoader.data.count == 0) ? UIImage(named: "apple")! : UIImage(data: imageLoader.data)!)
```

Comment: I just wonder: There is an [`Image(uiImage:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269665-init)  initializer, but I cannot see an `Image(from:)` initializer in the documentation.

Comment: the highest probability is that SwifttUI is too buggy in beta , as there is no translation for the above compile error except that given that this code is written for it and it's not a usual initialize

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error from the question, but `Image(from: ...)` does *not* compile in my test.